# dashboard.heroku.com Not Found. Has anybody seen this before?

Tags: heroku

I've just signed in to a new Heroku account and when I navigate to the Dashboard (dashboard.heroku.com), it says "The Page You Were Looking for Does Not Exist."

Has anybody seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps. Also, make sure you are signed in.